# What am I doing wrong? Batch file stopped functioning

Tags: batch-file, variables, counting

I haven't the slightest clue why, but this file stopped functioning recently.
Maybe I changed something and just don't remember.

The script is intended to correct the numbering structure of folders in 'database', with the numbers increasing from newest to oldest (starting at 0). The folder structure in 'database' just needs to be named similarly to the following: "1 - 2_12_2017" or "34 - 1_14_2017".

After some troubleshooting, I found that **set /a cnt=!cnt!+1** doesn't seem to be increasing **!cnt!**. Or rather, by the time the first *'for'* tree finishes and you hit **:loop**, **!cnt!** still equals -1, which causes the next section to quit after processing the first folder.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I hope one of you is able to figure it out.
As it stands, I'm out of ideas.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dbpth=C:\Users\Script Keeper\Desktop\backups\database"
set cnt=-1
cd %dbpth%
set "fy=unset"
set "fm=unset"
set "fd=unset"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-n "%dbpth%\*"') do (
    title Prunning Correction - %%A
    for /f "delims=1234567890-_ " %%B in ("%%A") do (
        if "%%B" == "" (
            set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
            set "str=%%A"
            set "str=!str:~-10!"
            set "str=!str: =!"
            set "str=!str:-=!"
            set "ys=unset"
            set "ms=unset"
            set "ds=unset"
            for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%F in ("!str!") do (
                if !ms! == unset (
                    set "ms=%%F"
                )
                if !ds! == unset (
                    set "ds=%%G"
                )
                if !ys! == unset (
                    set "ys=%%H"
                )
            )
            if !fy! == unset (
                set "fy=!ys!"
                set "fd=!ds!"
                set "fm=!ms!"
            )
            if not !fy! == unset (
                if !ys! leq !fy! (
                    set "fy=!ys!"
                    if !ms! leq !fm! (
                        set "fm=!ms!"
                        if !ds! leq !fd! (
                            set "fd=!ds!"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

:loop
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-n "%dbpth%\*"') do (
    title Prunning Correction - %%G
    set "str=%%G"
    set "str=!str:~-10!"
    set "str=!str: =!"
    set "str=!str:-=!"
    if !str! == !fm!_!fd!_!fy! (
        ren "%dbpth%\%%G" "!cnt! - !fm!_!fd!_!fy!"
        set /a cnt=!cnt!-1
    )
)
set /a fd=!fd!+1
if !fd! gtr 31 (
    set /a fm=!fm!+1
    set fd=1
    if !fm! gtr 12 (
        set /a fy=!fy!+1
        set fm=1
    )
)
title !cnt! - !fm!_!fd!_!fy!
if !cnt! geq 0 (goto loop)
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: remove `@echo off` and see the output on screen. You'll probably find some `if` statement not matching. Also, when you say _Batch file stopped functioning_ do you mean it did work before? If so, what changed since.

Comment: I've removed @echo off already and found nothing.
I've run the script with cmd /k and removing exit, still nothing.

The last time I've needed this script was about 5 or 6 months ago. If any changes happened since then, I don't remember them.

Comment: Without appearing rude, I think that it would be much easier were you to provide us with a list of genuine examples of your starting directory names together with their renamed equivalents, _(which appear to be in the form of `<increment><space>-<space>D_MM_YYYY`)_.

Comment: I apologize if my description of the naming scheme was too vague.
folders would be named just as you described; <increment><space>-<space>D_MM_YYYY     As an example, in folder "Database" would be folders named as the date the backup was taken, with the increment increasing from the newest folder to the oldest, starting from 0. Here are some such names; ||| 0 - 1_2_2018 ||| 1 - 31_1_2018 ||| 2 - 30_1_2018 ||| 3 - 26_12_2017